# How merge patches with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

Is there any way to merge patches with common edges?
I generate a sequence of patches opportunely styled using a matrix for understanding the edge color.
More in detail:

1. I read an image
2. I resize the image and divide it into tiles of 64x64
3. Cycle on each tile and built a matrix of value, one for each tile.

The result is a figure with patches which are styled on the base of the matrix value.

The following code works fine:

```
for row in range(0, h, dim):
for col in range(0, w, dim):
c_map2 = [(1,0,0,1),(0,0,1,1),(0.2,0.2,0.2,1),(0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,1)] #position 3 will be not visible
_p = patches.Rectangle((row, col), dim - 1, dim - 1, linewidth=1.5, fill=False, edgecolor=c_map2[int(y_class2)])
plt.gca().add_patch(_p)
```

Here an example of the matrix and the figure:

```
Show classes matrix
[[3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 4. 4. 4.]
 [4. 4. 2. 2.]
 [3. 2. 1. 2.]]
```

How can I delete the edge between patches with the same color, keeping only the outer edge of areas of the same color?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using matplotlib contour and contourf methods respectively for plotting ROIs' perimeter and for filling the ROIs.
More in detail:

1. I created a mask of 1 and 2 for the value x I needed to contour, where x was replaced by 1 and all other values by 2.

   new_matrix = np.where(old_matrix == 0, 1,2)
2. I defines two levels:

   level1 =  [0,1]
   level2 = [1,2]
3. I plotted the contour and the area:

   ax2.contour(new_matrix, levels1, colors='yellow', linewidths=1, zorder=1)

   ax3.contourf(new_matrix, levels1, colors='yellow', alpha=0.5)

   ax3.contourf(new_matrix, levels2, colors='gray', alpha=0)